# Why does myDataTable.AsEnumerable().DefaultIfEmpty(myDataTable.NewRow()).First(...) NOT return myDataTable.NewRow() when .First(...) is empty?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am attempting to get either the first row of a data table that has it's primary key value equal to a value I am providing to this LINQ query, OR a new row from that table.

I've tried

```
DataRow Foo = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().DefaultIfEmpty(myDataTable.NewRow()).First(Row => Row.Field<string>("KEY").equals("Bar"))
```

but it throws an `InvalidOperationException`, telling me 'Sequence contains no matching element'.

I've tried something similar with

```
DataRow Foo = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().DefaultIfEmpty(myDataTable.NewRow()).FirstOrDefault(Row => Row.Field<string>("KEY").equals("Bar"))
```

because I thought that would return the value I specified in `DefaultIfEmpty(...)`, but it only ever returned null.

So... what am I doing wrong here? Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Apparently `Row.Field<string>("KEY").equals("Bar")` is never satisfied...

Comment: Yes, then why does it not return myDataTable.newRow(), as specified by the .DefaultIfEmpty() extension?

Comment: `DefaultIfEmpty()` ensures that you will have something to query against if the collection is empty, it has no effect on your predicate in the `First()` call.

Comment: Okay; I understand then. I would need to set the value of myDataTable.newRow() KEY field equal to the value on which I am querying in order for .First(...) to return for what I am looking, always. That makes sense to me. How would I go about doing that? Is there a way to do that in line, or am I going to have to declare and set the value outside of the lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your query ought to be:

```
var key = "Bar";
var foo = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .FirstOrDefault(row => row.Field<string>("KEY") == key) ?? myDataTable.NewRow();
```

All that `DefaultIfEmpty()` provides for you is an item to query against if the collection is empty.  The problem is that by using `First()`, a row that satisfies the condition *must* be found. Apparently you didn't so an exception is thrown.